# How can i handle DZRPlayer finished playing current track?

Tags: ios, deezer

I tried to use `(void)player:(DZRPlayer *)player didBuffer:(long long)bufferedBytes outOf:(long long)totalBytes` to handle end of the track,  but it never has been called with buffered Bytes being the same as totalBytes.
Is it possible to handle track ends?

Comment: did you end up finding a solution to this?

Comment: @Tys I use the following code to handle end of the track
`- (void)player:(DZRPlayer *)player didStartPlayingTrack:(DZRTrack *)track {}` and you should check `self.player.currentTrack`. If it's undefined, then player finished to play previous track.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `progress` property of `DZRPlayer` can come in handy.

```
/*!
The progress in the playback of the current playing DZRTrack.

This is the percentage of the track aldready played. You can assign to this 
property to seek inside the track.
*/
@property (nonatomic, assign) double progress;
```